# How to display a large widget with all timeline entries at once in widgetkit swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, widget

I have a task app with widgets and all of them are working great but I would like to add a large widget which will display many tasks (probably 5) at once but when getting data from Provider() it displays only one at a time like the other widgets.
Below the getTimeline and the widget codes. Could someone help on that ?

getTimeline:

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        
        var entries: [WidgetContent] = []
        
        let viewContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Task");
        
        let currentDate = Date()
        
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            
            var entry = snapshotEntry
            
            var results = [Task]()
            
            do { results = try viewContext.fetch(request) as! [Task] }
            
            catch let error as NSError { print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)") }
            
            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(results.count)))
            
            let displayComplete = results[randomIndex].isComplete
            let displayAdded = results[randomIndex].dateAdded
            let displayName = results[randomIndex].name
            let displayCategory = results[randomIndex].secondaryCategory
            let displayImportance = results[randomIndex].important
            let displayUrgency = results[randomIndex].urgent
            
            entry = WidgetContent(date: entryDate, isComplete: displayComplete, dateAdded: displayAdded!, name: displayName!, secondaryCategory: displayCategory!, important: displayImportance!, urgent: displayUrgency!)
            
            if !results[randomIndex].isComplete {
                
                entries.append(entry)
            }
        }
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

Widget:

```
struct Important2DoMultipleWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Important2DoMultipleWidget"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            DetailedEntryView(model: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Important2Do Widget Detailed Version")
        .description("Find your important and urgent things.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemLarge])
    }
}
```

Widget displayed (part of the code which matters):

```
struct LargeDetailedEntryView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family
    
    let model: [WidgetContent]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0 ..< model.count) { value in
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Spacer()
                        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline, spacing: 2) {
                            CategoryImageWidgetView(category: Category(rawValue: model[value].secondaryCategory)!)
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .padding(.all, 5)
                                .foregroundColor(Category(rawValue: model[value].secondaryCategory)!.color)
                                .background(Category(rawValue: model[value].secondaryCategory)!.color.opacity(0.3))
                                .cornerRadius(12)
                            Text(model[value].secondaryCategory)
                                .font(.caption)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .padding(.top, 8)
                        }
                        Spacer()
...
```

The model.count above just have 1 record always but it changes the task displayed with each entries on timeline correctly.
Below a picture on how it's looking right now, working as a regular widget and I would like to have multiple tasks into the same large widget.

[image: Widget working with only one task]

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. But it sounds like you need a `WidgetBundle` I don't see that in your code here is some [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension).

Comment: Also,  the [Widget Code Along](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie) has an example in I think part 3 when they talk about the Leaderboard Widget.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think it's reproducible as you can see into the image included into the code above and I just want to have additional tasks being displayed into the large widget. Code shared is enough for what is being displayed at the moment.